# Read tags from JPG using Exiftool and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, exif, exiftool

I am trying to get the tag metadata from a JPG image using NodeJS and the exiftool. This is the first time I am using NodeJS. This is what I tried:
    I installed NodeJS for windows. I have an image with the name t.jpg and in the same directory I have a js file called run.js

This is the run.js file

```
var exif = require('exiftool');
var fs   = require('fs');
fs.readFile('t.jpg', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        exif.metadata(data, function (err, metadata) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log(metadata);
        });
    }
});
```

I then opened a command line window and typed the following:

I assumed I needed to add whatever was required in the code

```
npm install exiftool
npm install fs
node run.js
```

I then got the following error:

```
> node run.js
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:710:26)
    at Socket._write (net.js:729:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:333:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:319:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:246:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:656:40)
    at Object.exports.metadata (C:\Users\chris\Dropbox\Werk\nodejs\no
    at C:\Users\chris\Dropbox\Werk\nodejs\run.js:7:10
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? What can I do to get what I want?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, it works for me. Looks like some system related issue, like permissions, or `exiftool` not in PATH. Are you able to run `exiftool` from command line (CMD or powershell)?

Comment: Thank you... I didn't have exiftool in my windows folder. If you write this as an answer I can give you the rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See comments -> `exiftool` must be installed in system PATH. To easily test this, try running `exiftool` from command line (cmd or powershell).

Comment: I get the same error even though i can run exiftool from command line, same code as above. any thought?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install exiftool, verify this by running exiftool in terminal. Or better still install npm package "dist-exiftool", it also installs exiftool file.exe, but in the node_modules of your project. An additional package "node-exiftool", provides node functions for working with exiftool.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32565477)